# GETTING ERROR POSTING FILE TO MYSQL - PHP-CRUD-API

Tags: php, angular, http-post

I'm trying to upload an image using mevdschee's PHP-CRUD-API.
I've tried almost everything..
theese are the service functions I've tried, using both FormData or simple json.

service.ts

```
addMapIcon(mapIcon:mapIcon): Observable<string>{
    let fd = new FormData;
    fd.append('active', mapIcon.active?'1':'0');
    fd.append('file',mapIcon.file);
    fd.append('name',mapIcon.name);
    return this.http.post<string>(this.iconApiUrl, fd);

..or even:

    return this.http.post<string>(this.iconApiUrl, fd, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-type':'multipart/form-data'
          + combination of others parameters
          }));
    
  }
```

```
addMapIcon(mapIcon:mapIcon): Observable<string>{
      return this.http.post<string>(this.iconApiUrl, mapIcon, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }),
        });  
      }
```

component.ts

```
onIconChange(e) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    
    if(e.target.files && e.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = e.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.mapIcon.file = file; //(or even reader.result as string; as found in some example)
        this.mapIcon.name = file.name;
        this.mapIcon.active = true;
        //this.icon.file = file;
        /*this.uploadForm.patchValue({
          imgSrc: reader.result
        });*/
   
      };
    }
  }
```

the file field is defined as mediumblob in mysql.

The error I get is **"Data integrity violation"**.

Can't understand where the error is..

Comment: If you're going to post an error message, post all of it. There appears to be a problem with your MySQL schema but you've only posted part of the error message and none of the relevant code or table structure.

Comment: I'm using mevdschee's treeql PDO PHP-CRUD-API, the only message I get is 1010 - "Data integrity violation".

Comment: https://treeql.org/learn/, search 1010, is a conflit. I'm trying to post via swagger but again get the error. I only can post if I put a little string in the file field (via swagger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Data integrity violation" error is caused by a failing constraint. This may be:

- a foreign key constraint that is failing (referenced record does not exist)
- a missing field value (on a field without a default value)
- a null value where it is not allowed (the field is not nullable)

You may enable debug mode (`'debug' => true` in the config) and look at the `X-Exception-Message` HTTP header of the response (using the Network tab of the Developer tools of your browser). It will contain the cause of the problem.

NB: I am "mevdschee", the author of the PHP-CRUD-API.

Comment: I've looked around how to enable debug in the docs.. but haven't found..my bad. thank u so much

Comment: @NikRubblers Please accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

are you able to send image blob successfully to backend using post request? If not try this :

```
addMapIcon(mapIcon:mapIcon): Observable<string>{
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('active', mapIcon.active?'1':'0');
    **fd.append('file',mapIcon.file, mapIcon.name);**
    fd.append('name',mapIcon.name);

    return this.http.post<string>(this.iconApiUrl, fd, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-type':'multipart/form-data'
          }));
  }
```